# Upload Failed When phone call received IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I use afnetworking to upload.When phone call received upload process becomes failure.What should i do?

MY Codes for uploading:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *paraDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[paraDict setObject:str_ImageData forKey:Content];
[paraDict setObject:str_ImageName forKey:Name];

 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",API_URL,Upload_Image] parameters:paraDict error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@",str_ImageName);
    NSLog(@"tamam");
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseData) {
```

---

```
 [requestOperation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    double percentDone = (double)totalBytesWritten / (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    NSLog(@"progress updated(percentDone) : %f", percentDone);
    progressView2.progress = percentDone;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1- go to target section .

2- then Capabilities.

3- then background moode.

4- On background mode.

5- tick whatever u want to perform in background .

Hope it will help u